# How do I rig this so the wings are symmetrical?

Tags: rigging

How do I rig my flying machine so the wings can be flapped symmetrically? I'd like to have it so that when I move one side, the other moves as well.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kf_ba7BVAo4&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: You can use Bone Constraints for that (try Copy Rotation, with the "Invert" setting on the right axis)

Comment: went to look at the video answer, link is broken.
don't know if you need this but its a flying rig.
and is more entailed than your model and
not sure if you can adapt it or not I reworked it some and it works. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C5MKQ9Vrl3hZC193DZE2lBJUtGuLPRoP

Answer (score 1):

- In *Edit* mode, copy your "wing_L" bone with the *Symmetrize* function to automatically create a "wing_R" bone.
- Switch to *Pose* mode, select the right wing and give it a *Copy Rotation* constraint.
- Copy the exact same setup as the one on the screenshot: Enable X, Y and Z axis, enable the *Invert* option of Y and Z, choose *Space* > *Local Space* / *Local Space*.
- It should work.

[image]

You could also simply, in *Pose* mode, copy the left bone pose with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and paste to the right bone with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. Just don't forget to insert a keyframe for the right bone (<kbd>i</kbd>).